# How to decrypt DASH mp4protection with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can watch the live stream video from android device but can't watch on Windows. 
Is it possible to download and decrypt it with FFMPEG ?

the sample playlist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
     profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
     type="dynamic"
     minimumUpdatePeriod="PT4.974S" 
     publishTime="2019-04-05T08:58:38Z" 
     availabilityStartTime="2019-03-29T01:42:08Z" 
     timeShiftBufferDepth="PT40.0S"
     suggestedPresentationDelay="PT8.0S" 
     minBufferTime="PT6.0S">
    <ProgramInformation>
        <Title>abcdefg.smil</Title>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <Location>https://xxx.yyy.zzz/liveedge_ezdrm/abcdefg.smil/manifest_w43695283_qYXBwaWQ9dHJ1ZWlkdjImdHlwZT1saXZlJnZpc2l0b3I9bW9iaWxlJnVpZD00MzM1MTE1MA==.mpd</Location>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" group="1" mimeType="video/mp4" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" par="16:9" frameRate="25" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="67e5babd-0e78-5cd0-bccd-bae46f10b3c6"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" value="Widevine">
                <cenc:pssh>AAAAM3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABMiC3NpbGVudF9tYXJ5SOPclZsG</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cs$Time$_w43695283_qYXBwaWQ9dHJ1ZWlkdjImdHlwZT1saXZlJnZpc2l0b3I9bW9iaWxlJnVpZD00MzM1MTE1MA==_mpd.m4s" initialization="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cinit_w43695283_qYXBwaWQ9dHJ1ZWlkdjImdHlwZT1saXZlJnZpc2l0b3I9bW9iaWxlJnVpZD00MzM1MTE1MA==_mpd.m4s">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="56785491720" d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                    <S d="360000"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
            <Representation id="p0va0br818380" codecs="avc1.4d401e" width="640" height="360" sar="1:1" bandwidth="818380" />
            <Representation id="p0va0br1258291" codecs="avc1.4d401e" width="854" height="480" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1258291" />
            <Representation id="p0va0br1887436" codecs="avc1.4d401f" width="960" height="540" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1887436" />
            <Representation id="p0va0br2537779" codecs="avc1.4d401f" width="1280" height="720" sar="1:1" bandwidth="2537779" />
            <Representation id="p0va0br463974" codecs="avc1.4d4015" width="426" height="240" sar="1:1" bandwidth="463974" />
            <Representation id="p0va0br131891" codecs="avc1.42c00c" width="320" height="180" sar="1:1" bandwidth="131891" />
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" group="2" mimeType="audio/mp4" lang="th" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="67e5babd-0e78-5cd0-bccd-bae46f10b3c6"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" value="Widevine">
                <cenc:pssh>AAAAM3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABMiC3NpbGVudF9tYXJ5SOPclZsG</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="48000" media="chunk_ctaudio_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cs$Time$_w43695283_qYXBwaWQ9dHJ1ZWlkdjImdHlwZT1saXZlJnZpc2l0b3I9bW9iaWxlJnVpZD00MzM1MTE1MA==_mpd.m4s" initialization="chunk_ctaudio_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cinit_w43695283_qYXBwaWQ9dHJ1ZWlkdjImdHlwZT1saXZlJnZpc2l0b3I9bW9iaWxlJnVpZD00MzM1MTE1MA==_mpd.m4s">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="30285595824" d="192528"/>
                    <S d="191472"/>
                    <S d="192528"/>
                    <S d="191472"/>
                    <S d="192528"/>
                    <S d="191472"/>
                    <S d="192528"/>
                    <S d="191472"/>
                    <S d="192528"/>
                    <S d="191472"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
            <Representation id="p0aa0br65536" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="48000" bandwidth="65536">
        </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
    <UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:direct:2014" value="2019-04-05T08:58:38Z"/>
</MPD>
```

Comment: asking for assistance hacking an encrypted stream? cheeky.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a Widevine level 3 response from the license server, there have been successful DFA attacks used to extract the key. Levels 2 and 1 have never been broken.

It works on Android because Android includes a secure enclave that prevents keys from leaking.